# Facing hard encryption

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

I have a little problem with encryption. I have this cipher text "AA969CF9657F77C597C8EAFF1594D59374E4977F" and i know that correspond to "http://jogos.meo.pt/". I have another samples, but i can´t find any analogy or logic, with the intuit to discover the algorithm of encryption. Can anybody help me??I really need this...!

Comment: another sample: cipher-text "AA969CF9657F77FEA9F4D3F5CA96E17099E27F" plan-text "xxxx://meojogos.pt/" xxxx equal to http

Comment: another one: cipher-text "93AA94" plan-text "nao"

Comment: Smells like a SHA-1 hash to me.

Comment: why you conclude that?

Comment: Definitely not SHA-1, or any other proper hash. The 3rd one is not the right length, and the first two are not different enough. I would guess that this is NOT hard encryption, but some simple substitution / rotation. Probably easy enough to crack with basic cryptanalysis.

Comment: can you give any ideas? How do you start for example?

Answer (score 1):

From the samples you gave, it doesn't look like very sophisticated encryption.  What you're trying to do is a Known-plaintext attack on this system.

> The known-plaintext attack (KPA) is an attack model for cryptanalysis where the attacker has samples of both the plaintext (called a crib), and its encrypted version (ciphertext). These can be used to reveal further secret information such as secret keys and code books. [Wikipedia entry on Known-plaintext Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack)

For example, the first `h` appears to be consistently encrypted to `AA`.  The last example two letters `n` and `o` have sequential encryptions: `93` and `94`.  You may be able to find other commonalities.

The odd part of this is that you have access to a lot of plain-text and cipher-text.  This seems to indicate that you can encrypt what you want, or a chosen-plaintext attack.  These are usually more informative than known-plaintext.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don´t understand why 'AA' in the first position correspond to 'h' always, but in second position correspond to 'a'. I need to understand the algorithm, because i want to decrypt this hex '7E6E7E1D63' and i do not have enough samples to make analogy.

Comment: i can had other sample like this one '92A094CE94A397F674FAE2' correspond to 'meojogos.pt'

Answer (score 1):

Look at the ciphertexts you have, and look for similarities.  If you can find similarities, it may be a weak cipher. For example,

- your ciphertext is always twice as long as your plaintext.
- look at the characters in the ciphertext. They're hexadecimal (0-F).  Two hexadecimal characters can represent one byte - one character in a computer. This matches with my previous point very nicely - each character is being encoded as a hexidecimal value
- wherever there's an 'h' in your plaintext, there's an 'AA' in your ciphertext (well, at twice the distance into the ciphertext - if 'h' is at index 5, 'AA' is at index 10).
- the '/' character always seems to encode as 7F, regardless of index in the string

This implies a simple substitution cipher with output hex encoded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don´t understand why 'AA' in the first position correspond to 'h' always, but in second position correspond to 'a'. I need to understand the algorithm, because i want to decrypt this hex '7E6E7E1D63' and i do not have enough samples to make analogy.

Comment: i can had other sample like this one '92A094CE94A397F674FAE2' correspond to 'meojogos.pt'.